# NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a question about my htaccess file and an apache warning I keep getting.

```
RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.
```

This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

#This will send anything after recruit as a get variable
#www.example.com/recruit123 -> www.example.com/recruit.php?id=/123

RewriteRule ^recruit(.*)$ recruit.php?id=/$1 [QSA,L]

#Add .php extension only for URIs that are not file or 
#directories and that are already valid php files.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

I have read in many posts that I need to change

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

but as you can see, this is not my case since my file has the correct line.

Would the issue be with

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
```

do i have to add a ! to make it

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php !-f [NC]
```

Any help I could get will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod%5Frewrite.html#rewritecond) for a while:

The `[NC]` flag is for regex matching rules, but you're not testing a regex, you're testing if the file exists with `-f`. `-f` is not a regular expression so it throws the error:

> NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported

Comment: The `$1` works in a rewrite cond because *the pattern in a `RewriteRule` is applied **first**.* Then the conditions are checked.